# Apple's SpeakHere demo, mixing ObjC and C++, and translation units

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios

Using Apple's SpeakHere demo as starting point, I want to implement a sound waveform instead of a level meter. I added another view, SoundWaveView, an ObjC class, alongside the GLLevelMeter, and modelled its implementation on the AQLevelMeter.mm class.

After finding that the file should be named ".mm", the code compiles, but when executing, it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the MeterTable object. Printing this object in the debugger gives the following:

```
error: instance method 'setMeterTable:' has a different number of parameters in different translation units (0 vs. 1)
error: instance method 'setMeterTable:' has a different number of parameters in different translation units (0 vs. 1)
note: instance method 'setMeterTable:' also declared here
note: instance method 'setMeterTable:' also declared here
error: 2 errors parsing expression
```

Now I suspect that including the MeterTable.h in both AQLevelMeter.mm (Apple) and SoundWaveView.mm (mine) gives me the duplication, but how can I access MeterTable from my class without importing the .h??

Comment: Can you show us the `MeterTable.h` file and perhaps a little bit about the `AQLevelMeter` and `SoundWaveView` classes?

Comment: I don't think it's complaining about duplication so much as multiple declarations that don't quite match.  (You might also want to set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions to get a better description of what's causing the crash.)

Comment: SOLVED: I still have no idea what caused the debugger messages, or why they went away. Looking into the bad access exception a little deeper, I discovered that I forgot to initialize the relevant array, so accessing this array caused the access exception. So in effect, adding a variable assignment cleared these debugger messages as well. Sometimes magic is nice! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to initialize all the nasty pointer stuff. Or choose another language for less worries (sorry, I couldn't  resist).